# Why does each single character of the string not equal to the character equivalent?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to check if each character of a string in a string array is equal to any of the five vowels. However, when I test it to see when a vowel character in a string is equal to 'vowel', I get that they are not equal. The problem with the code is the bolded part below. Also, when I try to do "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u", I get the error that ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer. How can I be able to check if they are equal? Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int l, c; //l is amount of letters in password, c is amount of letters being inputted
char letters[1000000]; //the letters being inputted

vector <string> pass; //string vector of the stored passwords
void rec(string current, int index, int x){ //determining all possible passwords
    if (index >= 4){
        pass.push_back(current);
    }
    else{
        for (int i=0; i<c; i++){
            if (x<i){
                int old;
                old = x;
                x = i;
                rec(current + letters[i], index+1, x);
                x = old;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{

    cin >> l >> c;

    int x = -1;

    for (int i=0; i<c ;i++){
        cin >> letters[i];
    }

    sort(letters, letters + c); //sorted from least to greatest

    rec("", 0, x);
    for (int i=0; i<pass.size(); i++){
        int vl=0; //number of vowels
        int nvl=0; //number of non-vowels (consonants)

        for (int j=0; j<l; j++){
            **if (pass.at(0)[j] == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'){**
                vl++;
            }
            else{
                nvl++;
            }
            if (j == l-1){
                if (vl >= 1 && nvl >= 2){
                    cout << pass.at(0) << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "bolded" part of the code is the part that has the two asterisks

Comment: Take a look at some other examples of if statements with multiple clauses.  That statement is doing something different than what you intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, `X || Y` means:

- Test if `X` is true. If so, result of whole expression is `true`
- Otherwise, test if `Y` is true. Result of `Y` is result of expression.

So your code:

```
pass.at(0)[j] == 'a' || 'e'
```

(omitting for now the `i` etc. as they don't change anything).

We tested `pass.at(0)[j] == 'a'`  . That was false, so now we test `'e'`.  Not that you did NOT test `pass.at(0)[j] == 'e'`. You just tested `'e'`.  This is the same as testing `'e' != 0`, which is true.  So your expression evaluates to `true` at this point (and does not go onto check `'i'` etc.)

You probably intended to test whether `pass.at(0)[j]` held any of the values `'a'`, `'e'`, etc.  If so then one way to encode that is:

```
if ( std::strchr("aeiou", pass.at(0)[j]) )
```

You should make sure `j < strlen(pass.at(0))` before doing this though; using `[]` to generate an out of bounds index causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks M.M for how to check if any of the characters in the string is a, e, i, o, or u!

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using the `||` wrong. The part either side of `||` is a "true or false" expressin in itself, so you need something like:

```
if (pass.at(0)[j] == 'a' || pass.at(0)[j] == 'e' ... )
```

Otherwise, the expression is always true, since `||` is true if the expression on left or right is true, and `'e'` is true by not being zero.

Comment: Thanks Mats for telling me that pass.at(0)[j] == 'a' || 'e'... is not what I intended! This helped me realize that those are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

This does not do what you think...

```
(pass.at(0)[j] == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')
```

You need to explicitly compare,

```
char t = pass.at(0)[j];

if (t == 'a' || t == 'e' || t == 'i' || t == 'o' || t == 'u') {
```